# Xpath - Group matches as combined results

Tags: xpath

I'm having the following problem, I want to create a Xpath expression that results into 3 matches, where match1=text1text1text, match2=text2text2text2 etc.

I'm able to find each p seperate, but i just can't 'group' them.

What the expression should say is: "after a[@class="random-a-tag"] give me all the text of all the p-tags that exist before each element where div[@id]"

```
 <a class="random-a-tag"></a>
 <p>text1</p>
 <p>text1</p>
 <p>text1</p>
 <div id="1"></div>
 <p>text2</p>
 <p>text2</p>
 <p>text2</p>
 <div id="2"></div>
 <p>text3</p>
 <p>text3</p>
 <p>text3</p>
 <div id="3"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps.

find all divs

```
//a[@class="random-a-tag"]/following-sibling::div[@id]
```

and for each div @id do:

```
//a[@class="random-a-tag"]/following-sibling::p[following-sibling::div[1][@id="3"]]/text()
```

Answer (score 1):

**This cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression**.

The most you can select is the set of `p` for a given value of `@id`:

```
      /*/a/following-sibling::div
        [@id=$pId]
           /preceding-sibling::p
             [count(.
                   |
                    /*/a/following-sibling::div
                                  [@id=$pId]
                                    /preceding-sibling::div[1]
                                       /preceding-sibling::p
                    )
            =
              count(/*/a/following-sibling::div
                                  [@id=$pId]
                                    /preceding-sibling::div[1]
                                       /preceding-sibling::p
                    )
               +1
           ]
```

**If `$pId` is (substituted by) 2, and the above XPath expression is applied on this XML document** (your XML fragment, wrapped in a top element to make it well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <a class="random-a-tag"></a>
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text1</p>
    <div id="1"></div>
    <p>text2</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <p>text3</p>
    <div id="3"></div>
</t>
```

**then this selects the following nodes**:

```
<p>text2</p>
<p>text2</p>
<p>text2</p>
```

In the above XPath expression we use the wellknown Kayessian (created by @Michael Kay) formula for node-set intersection:

```
$ns1[count(.|$ns2) = count($ns2)]
```

is the intersection of the nodesets `$ns1` and `$ns2`.

**II. XPath 2.0 solution**:

```
 (a/following-sibling::div
                  [@id=$pId]
                    /preceding-sibling::p
except
  a/following-sibling::div
                  [@id=$pId]
                    /preceding-sibling::div[1]
                       /preceding-sibling::p
  )/string()
```

**When this XPath 2.0 expression is evaluated against the same XML document (above) and `$pId` is 2, the result is exactly the wanted text**:

```
text2 text2 text2
```